# Regex in Python for html

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to write a regex expression for:

```
<td class="prodSpecAtribute" rowspan="2">[words]</td>
```

or

```
<td class="prodSpecAtribute">[words]</td>
```

for the second case I have:

```
find2 = re.compile('<td class="prodSpecAtribute">(.*)</td>')
```

But, how can I create a regex which can use either of the 2 expressions

Comment: Are you limited to regex in this situation?  Sometimes it's safer to not use regex for HTML parsing... (see [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), or *[something similar](http://htmlparsing.com/)*...)

Comment: Python has a good [HTML parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)

Comment: <td class="prodSpecAtribute"[^>]*?>(.*?)</td>

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Well, before 2.7.3 and 3.2.something it's actually kind of slow and finicky… but yeah, still better than trying to solve an HTML parsing problem with regex.

Comment: It's pretty simple to use xpath for this kind of tasks.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/45786?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for this, use an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup.  For example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup1 = BeautifulSoup('<td class="prodSpecAtribute" rowspan="2">[words]</td>')
>>> soup1.find('td', class_='prodSpecAtribute').contents[0]
u'[words]'
>>> soup2 = BeautifulSoup('<td class="prodSpecAtribute">[words]</td>')
>>> soup2.find('td', class_='prodSpecAtribute').contents[0]
u'[words]'
```

Or to find all matches:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='prodSpecAtribute'):
    print td.contents[0]
```

With BeautifulSoup 3:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for td in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'prodSpecAtribute'}):
    print td.contents[0]
```

Comment: I might use `find_all` here instead to handle the multiple-tag case.

Comment: @DSM could you please elaborate, I didn't understand your point. Thanks

Comment: Would this be correct:     'soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    info = soup.findAll('td', class_= prodSpecAtribute)'

Comment: @F.J I get an error:     for elements in soup.findall('td', class_= 'prodSpecAtribtue'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: This indicates that `soup` is `None`, did you import BeautifulSoup and use `soup = BeautifulSoup(page)` before this?

Comment: See my edit, the issue you were seeing was due to a difference between versions.

Comment: @F.J So, this is what I'm doing now:     soup = BeautifulSoup(page), 
    info = soup.findAll('td', {'class' : 'prodSpecAtribtue'}), 
    print info, do you know why the output is []?

Comment: I find the machinery of Beautiful Soup unjustified in your case. Use the solution of Zsolt Botykai in which ``(.*)`` must however be changed to ``(.*?)``

Answer (score 3):

if you ask for a regex:

```
find2 = re.compile('<td class="prodSpecAtribute"( rowspan="2")?>(.*)</td>')
```

But I would use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Great answer. But you might want to show how simple and readable the `BeautifulSoup` one-liner solution is.

Answer (score 0):

```
find2 = re.compile('<td class="prodSpecAtribute"[^>]*>(.*)</td>')
```

Will work. But there are better solutions for HTML parsing...

Comment: You must limit the greedy nature of .*

Comment: @eyquem No I must not. The one who asked a question must. And for the sample data he had provided my solution works. But you are right of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend neither regex nor BeautifulSoup. There is a project pyquery http://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/ that is much faster as it uses lxml.html library, speed comparasion can be found here: http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/03/30/python-html-parser-performance/. From my own experience BeautifulSoup is really slow.

So in your situation it is easy as this code:

```
>>>from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
>>>page = pq('<td class="prodSpecAtribute">[words]</td>')
>>>page('.prodSpecAtribute').text()
>>>'[words]'
```

Once again BS is really slow.